# Derivation of downsampling in the frequency domain

Tags: frequency-domain, downsampling, derivation

I'm having some trouble with [this derivation](https://www.projectrhea.org/rhea/index.php/Frequency_Downsampling)

$$s_d = \begin{cases}1&\text{for}\quad m\quad\text{multiples of}\quad D\\ 0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

then $s_d$ is somehow rewritten to:

$$\frac{1}{D}\sum_{k=0}^{D-1}e^{jk2\pi \frac{m}{D}} $$

Can someone explain this?

**EDIT:**

Basically the same derivation as done here
[Frequency Representation of Downsampled Signal](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/27540/frequency-representation-of-downsampled-signal?rq=1)

Comment: Where in the derivations are you having trouble specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression

$$s_d[m] = \frac{1}{D}\sum_{k=0}^{D-1}\exp(j2\pi \frac{km}{D})$$

is the Fourier series expansion of the periodic function $s_d[m]$ in the discrete case (i.e. only up to a certain amount of frequencies).

$s_d[m]$ is a also called comb function, and I have written more about it (including the relation you ask for) [in one of my articles](http://dspillustrations.com/pages/posts/misc/the-dirac-comb-and-its-fourier-transform.html?rid=so12).

Furthermore, here's some example Python code that verifies the correctness:

```
m = np.arange(64)
D = 16
sdm = 1/D*sum(np.exp(2j*np.pi*k*m/D) for k in range(D))
plt.plot(m, sdm.real)
```

[image]

The picture shows the Comb function, where every 16 samples the values becomes one, else zero.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I like to think about the expression

$$ \displaystyle \frac{1}{D} \sum_{k=0}^{D-1} e^{j 2 \pi k m / D}. $$

1. For any value of $D$, the first term is 1, and all of the terms lie on the unit circle.
2. Assuming $D > 1$, each term after the first is found by rotating the previous
   term through an angle of $2 \pi m / D$ radians.
3. If $m$ is not a multiple of $D$, then the resulting terms will be $D$ complex numbers that are evenly distributed about the unit circle, and will sum to zero.  This can be shown explicitly using the finite geometric series.
   $$
       \sum_{k=0}^{D-1} e^{j 2 \pi k m / D}
       = \frac{1 - e^{j 2 \pi D m / D}}{1 - e^{j 2 \pi m / D}}
       = \frac{1 - 1}{1 - e^{j 2 \pi m / D}}
       = 0.
   $$
4. If $m$ is a multiple of $D$, all of the terms in the sum will be 1, so the sum will be $D$, and the expression evaluates to 1.

Therefore, this sum is equivalent to $s_d[m]$, and as the previous answer correctly stated, it is the discrete-time Fourier series representation for a periodic impulse train or comb function.